# How to convert objects to array with jq

Tags: json, jq

I would like to transform with jq this JSON

```
[
  {
    "one": 37,
    "two": "2017-09-15T19:31:55"
  }
]
```

to this one

```
[
  {
    "one": 37
  },
  {
    "two": "2017-09-15T19:31:55"
  }
]
```

How to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to manipulations involving the keys of JSON objects, `to_entries` (and its friend, `with_entries`) are your friends:

```
map(to_entries[] | {(.key): .value})
```

Note also the parentheses around `.key`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm becoming mad, because I had no idea of (.key) to print the value of key as key of output object. Thank you very much